# How can I save dynamic input with multiple fields to database Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

Im working on a project using laravel. One function of the site is to save data from a dynamic input with four data;
MObjective, MOutput, year, and kra_id which should be saved to database

i tried using this code to save;
'''
  $objectives = $request->all();

```
    foreach ($objectives as $key) {
        // dd($input);
        $input = objective::create(array(
            'MObjective' => $objectives->MObjective[$key],
            'MOutput' => $objectives->MOutput[$key],
            'year' => $objectives->year,
            'kra_id' => $objectives->kra_id

        ));
      }
```

'''
I also tried to use for loop however i got some error like; Trying to get property 'MObjective' of non-object

this is may controller;

```
  $objectives = $request->all();
        foreach ($objectives as $key) {
            // dd($input);
            $input = objective::create(array(
                'MObjective' => $objectives->MObjective[$key],
                'MOutput' => $objectives->MOutput[$key],
                'year' => $objectives->year,
                'kra_id' => $objectives->kra_id

            ));
          }
```

my blade file;

```
  <form method="POST" action="{{action('ObjectiveController@store')}}">
              {{csrf_field()}}
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="year" id="year" value="{{now()->year}}" class="form-control">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="kra_id" name="kra_id">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Major Objective:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="MObjective" name="MObjective"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Major Output:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="MajorOutput" name="MOutput"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <b><i>Note:</i></b>
                <small>Add Major Objective and Output for selected KRA only</small>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

my script
'''

```
var i=0;
  $('.addRow').on('click', function(){
    i++;
    addRow();
  });
  function addRow()
  {
    var tr='<div class="row">'+'<div class="col-6"><textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Major Objective no. '+i+' "name="MObjective['+i+']"></textarea></div>'+
      '<div class="col-6"><textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="MOutput['+i+']" placeholder="Enter Major Output for the objective no. '+i+'"></textarea></div>'+
      '</div><br>';
    $('form').append(tr);
  }
```

'''

i just need to save the 4 data within one db table; MObjective, MOutput, year, and kra_id. I hope someone could help me. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller $objectives should be an array not an object if am not mistaken.